# Can't .load() PHP page that contains instance of class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I'm making an interactive menu, that loads pages with jQuery .load() function.

[image: interactive menu]

First button (which displays main feed with videos) loads file **feed.php** that contains only an instance of Class and then method call:

```
<h3>Main feed</h3>
<?php
    $videos = new Video();
    $videos->getVideos();
?>
```

Class **Video()** is defined in the file **function.php** that is included.

Tree:

> index.php
>  —init.php (DB)
>  ——functions.php
>  —header.php (Logo
>   & Menu itself)
>  —content.php (#content divs)
>  ——feed.php (Main
>   feed)

When i refresh page, feed is loaded without a problem.
But when i click on the first button, jQuery try to load **feed.php** into #content element, but fails.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Other buttons are working fine.

**Is this way of doing it wrong? Or am i just missing something?**

Comment: "Error 500" basically means you need to see the server log for the exact error message. If you're coding in PHP, that normally means you haven't configured PHP to display error messages.

Comment: In that case, can you add the contents of the `content.php` file?

Comment: "Fatal error: Class 'Video' not found in /var/www/clients/client19/web63/web/feed.php on line 6"

Which means i would need to include class Video() inside feed.php, but that would be just copy of one i already included.

Comment: use `require_once()` instead, and require in both files. The `require_once` statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

Comment: @MubinKhalid This solved the problem and i learned a new thing. Thanks!

Comment: It is fine for me, but if you wish, you can. I will make it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

`require_once 'link_to_php_file.php';`

you can use it in both(whatever number of files in which you want to use) files, but the file will get included just for once.

from the official `PHP` doc.

> The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

visit [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) for more information.

Hope this will help someone else too.